# Why one bname value showing its paramName count times in tableview while parsing in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, dictionary

my JSON:

```
  {
  "id": "70",
  "bname": "Municipal Corporation - Water",
  "bcategoryname": "Water",
  "bcustomerparms": "[{\"paramName\":\"Consumer Number\",\"dataType\":\"NUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"1\",\"maxLength\":\"10\"},
               {\"paramName\":\"Mobile Number\",\"dataType\":\"NUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"10\",\"maxLength\":\"10\"},
               {\"paramName\":\"Email . Id\",\"dataType\":\"ALPHANUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"5\",\"maxLength\":\"100\"}]",
  }
  "id": "68",
  "bname": "Municipal Corporation - 12",
  "bcategoryname": "Water",
  "bcustomerparms": "[{\"paramName\":\"K No\",\"dataType\":\"ALPHANUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"7\",\"maxLength\":\"20\"}]",
  }
```

here i am getting `Municipal Corporation - Water` three times in tableview, i need it one time and its paramName should be three in waterParamArray. like wise if there is one paramName then one value in waterParamArray.

[image]
   [image]

here is the code:

```
    do{
    let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
    //print("the all make payment json is \(jsonObj)")
    let billerdetailsArray = jsonObj["billerdetails"] as! [[String: Any]]

    for billerdetail in billerdetailsArray {

        self.categoryName = billerdetail["bcategoryname"] as? String

        let customrParams = billerdetail["bcustomerparms"] as! String
        let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:Data(customrParams.utf8)) as! [[String: Any]]

        for item in res {
            self.paramName = item["paramName"] as? String
            if self.categoryName == "Water"{
                let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                self.waterArray.append(bName ?? "")
                self.waterParamArray.append(self.paramName ?? "")
            }

            if self.categoryName == "Electricity"{
                let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                self.electricityArray.append(bName ?? "")
                self.electrictyParamArray.append(self.paramName ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let category = category else {return 0}
    switch category {
    case .electricity: return electricityArray.count
    case .water: return waterArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PaymentTableViewCell

    guard let category = category else {return cell}
    switch category {
    case .electricity: cell.pamntTypeLabel.text = electricityArray[indexPath.row]
    case .water: cell.pamntTypeLabel.text = waterArray[indexPath.row]

    }
    return cell
}
```

here textFieldList is nextVCs `var textFieldList = [String]()`, so that how many paramName it contains it will return that count

but all the time `textFieldList` contains single value why? even json contains three paramNames

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PaymentTableViewCell

if let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TextFiViewController") as? TextFiViewController
{
    switch category {
    case .electricity?: nextViewController.textFieldList = [electrictyParamArray[indexPath.row]]//electrictyParamArray[indexPath.row]

    case .water?: nextViewController.textFieldList = [waterParamArray[indexPath.row]]
    case .none:
        print("in didselect switch")
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
}
}
```

please help me in the above code.

Comment: As with your previous, similar question, it is very tough to get help with only fragments of your code. Review [mcve].

Comment: Are you getting all the parameter values same or just the name?

Comment: @Patel123 `Municipal Corporation - Water` contains three paramName so i am getting three times Municipal Corporation - Water in tableview, but i need one time Municipal Corporation - Water` and if i select then all three paramName to added to waterParamArray.......please help me in code i got stuck here from long time

Comment: id remains same ??

Comment: @Patel123, `for item in res {} ` bcoz of this line i am getting three times `Municipal Corporation - Water `

Comment: @Patel123, one thing how to add all three paramName in waterparamarray

Comment: Have you decode the data after JSONSerialzation , to store it in the model class  object?

Comment: @Patel123 no, thats why this issue, how to do that please tell me, i am unable to create struct to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202691/discussion-between-patel123-and-swift).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
struct MunicipalCorporation : Decodable{
    var id : String
    var bname : String
    var bbcategoryname : String
    var bcustomerparms : [Bcustomerparms]
}

struct Bcustomerparms : Decodable {
    var paramName : String
    var dataType : String
    var optional :  Bool?
    var minLength : Int
    var maxLength : Int
}
```

```
let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
let decoding = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MunicipalCorporation.self, from: jsonObj)
```

Comment: bcustomerparms is like this  "[{}]"

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftSamples/HomeIssue please go through this, and help me in code, got stuck from long time

Comment: wait... I'm looking

Comment: oh okay okay sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202703/discussion-between-patel123-and-swift).

Comment: from where you got stuck in your app , So that I can easily find the solution???

Comment: if u click water symble in home, then you can see all water `bname ` in that tableview... there if you click `Municipal Corporation Ludhiana - Water` then i need to show all its `paramName` values in three textfields

Comment: but there is only textfield created inside the tableview cell...

Comment: YES depend on number fo paramName count it will show three, or one

Comment: ok got it.. ```Municipal Corporation Ludhiana - Water``` on this basis you want all the bname in same table view

Comment: now u can see three `Municipal Corporation Ludhiana - Water` in table view and if u click 1st Municipal Corporation Ludhiana - Water then u can see `Consumer Number ` only, but i need only one Municipal Corporation Ludhiana - Water in tablevw and its three paramName means(Consumer Number. mobile number, email id) in nextvc textfield

Comment: I have edited question with screen shots, one Municipal Corporation Ludhiana - Water and if select then its three paramName in nextVC like above screen shot

Comment: have you understood the problrm, i have updated question

Comment: got the answer please reply