# How to create struct and init values from GET url in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, get

my JSON :

```
   {
  "id": "70",
  "bname": "Municipal Corporation - Water",
  "bcategoryname": "Water",
  "bcustomerparms": "[{\"paramName\":\"Consumer Number\",\"dataType\":\"NUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"1\",\"maxLength\":\"10\" .      },
           {\"paramName\":\"Mobile Number\",\"dataType\":\"NUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"10\",\"maxLength\":\"10\"},
           {\"paramName\":\"Email . Id\",\"dataType\":\"ALPHANUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"5\",\"maxLength\":\"100\"}]",
 }
  {    
 "id": "68",
 "bname": "Municipal Corporation - 12",
 "bcategoryname": "Water",
 "bcustomerparms": "[{\"paramName\":\"K No\",\"dataType\":\"ALPHANUMERIC\",\"optional\":\"false\",\"minLength\":\"7\",\"maxLength\":\"20\"}]",
 }
```

I am unable to create struct from get api, i need bname and its paramNamew according to its bcategoryname, i need to disply bname in table and if i select i need its all paramNames.

Here is code:

```
struct JsonDataBiller{
var bname: String?
var bcategoryname: String?
var bcustomerparms: [cDetails]

init(bname: String, bcategoryname: String, bcustomerparms: [cDetails]){

    self.bname = bname
    self.bcategoryname = bcategoryname
    self.bcustomerparms = bcustomerparms
}
}

struct cDetails{
var paramName: String?
var minLength: String?
var maxLength: String?

init(paramName: String, minLength: String, maxLength: String)
{
    self.paramName = paramName
    self.minLength = minLength
    self.maxLength = maxLength
}
}
```

Code:

```
class AllMakePaymentViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var jsonData = [JsonDataBiller]()

var minLength: String?
var maxLength: String?
var bName: String?
var category: Category?
var categoryName: String?
var paramName: String?

var ParamArray = [String]()

var labelText: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    allPaymentService()
}

func allPaymentService(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.anyemi.com/webservices/anyemi/api.php?rquest=billermdm"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            //print("the all make payment json is \(jsonObj)")
            let billerdetailsArray = jsonObj["billerdetails"] as! [[String: Any]]

            for billerdetail in billerdetailsArray {

                self.categoryName = billerdetail["bcategoryname"] as? String

                let customrParams = billerdetail["bcustomerparms"] as! String
                let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:Data(customrParams.utf8)) as! [[String: Any]]

                for item in res {

                    self.paramName = item["paramName"] as? String

                    self.minLength = item["minLength"] as? String
                    self.maxLength = item["maxLength"] as? String
                                            if self.categoryName == "Water"{
                        let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                        self.jsonData.append(JsonDataBiller(bname: bName ?? "", bcategoryname: self.categoryName ?? "", bcustomerparms: [paramName: paramName, minLength: minLength, maxLength: maxLength]))

                    }
                    if self.categoryName == "Electricity"{
                        let bName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String
                        self.jsonData.append(JsonDataBiller(bname: bName ?? "", bcategoryname: self.categoryName ?? "", bcustomerparms: [paramName: paramName, minLength: minLength, maxLength: maxLength]))
                    }
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }catch {
            print("catch error")
        } }).resume()
}
}
```

error:

> Contextual type '[cDetails]' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Here i need to add `bnam` according to its `bcategoryname` and `paramName` according to `bname`

please help me in the above code please, i am unable to solve this issue, i got stuck from long time.

Comment: You should use Codable... Things would be a lot simpler if you used that

Comment: @SchaheerSaleem, please post answer how to codable

Comment: Just google how to parse JSON with Codable protocol. Here is great tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/3418439-encoding-and-decoding-in-swift

Comment: @swift the json is not in correct format

Comment: Where does the error happen?

Comment: @JeremyP, `self.jsonData.append(JsonDataBiller` here , please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting close...

The key step issue is that you are looping through the "customer params" and adding a new customer object for each param, instead of adding *one* customer object that *includes* an array of params.

Take a look at this - it should run without any edits. After parsing the data, it will print the list of Water customers, along with their associated params.

The debug output should look like this:

```
Water count: 18
Electricity count: 71

Name: Bhopal Municipal Corporation - Water
Cat:  Water
Param: Connection ID / minLength: 8 / maxLength: 8

Name: Bangalore Water Supply and Sewerage Board
Cat:  Water
Param: RR Number / minLength: 8 / maxLength: 8

Name: Delhi Jal Board
Cat:  Water
Param: K No / minLength: 10 / maxLength: 10

...

Name: Municipal Corporation Jalandhar
Cat:  Water
Param: Account No / minLength: 1 / maxLength: 1
Param: Consumer Mobile No / minLength: 10 / maxLength: 10
Param: Consumer Email ID / minLength: 5 / maxLength: 5
Param: UID / minLength: 1 / maxLength: 1

Name: Municipal Corporation Ludhiana - Water
Cat:  Water
Param: Consumer Number / minLength: 1 / maxLength: 1
Param: Mobile Number / minLength: 10 / maxLength: 10
Param: Email Id / minLength: 5 / maxLength: 5

Name: New Delhi Municipal Council (NDMC) - Water
Cat:  Water
Param: Consumer Number / minLength: 7 / maxLength: 7

...
```

Here is the source:

```
//    
import UIKit

struct JsonDataBiller{
    var bname: String?
    var bcategoryname: String?
    var bcustomerparms: [cDetails]

    init(bname: String, bcategoryname: String, bcustomerparms: [cDetails]){

        self.bname = bname
        self.bcategoryname = bcategoryname
        self.bcustomerparms = bcustomerparms
    }
}

struct cDetails{
    var paramName: String?
    var minLength: String?
    var maxLength: String?

    init(paramName: String, minLength: String, maxLength: String)
    {
        self.paramName = paramName
        self.minLength = minLength
        self.maxLength = maxLength
    }
}

class AllMakePaymentViewController: UIViewController {

    // arrays of JsonDataBiller objects for each category
    var jsonWaterData = [JsonDataBiller]()
    var jsonElectricityData = [JsonDataBiller]()
    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        allPaymentService()
    }

    func allPaymentService(){

        let urlStr = "https://dev.anyemi.com/webservices/anyemi/api.php?rquest=billermdm"
        let url = URL(string: urlStr)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            guard let respData = data else {
                return
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            do{
                let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
                //print("the all make payment json is \(jsonObj)")
                let billerdetailsArray = jsonObj["billerdetails"] as! [[String: Any]]

                for billerdetail in billerdetailsArray {

                    // make these local vars --- no need for the confusing self. properties
                    let localBName = billerdetail["bname"] as? String ?? ""
                    let localCName = billerdetail["bcategoryname"] as? String  ?? ""

                    let customrParams = billerdetail["bcustomerparms"] as! String
                    let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:Data(customrParams.utf8)) as! [[String: Any]]

                    // create new array of cDetails objects
                    var aParams = [cDetails]()

                    // for each param item
                    for item in res {

                        if let pn = item["paramName"] as? String,
                            let minL = item["minLength"] as? String,
                            let maxL = item["maxLength"] as? String {

                            // create new cDetails object
                            let cd = cDetails(paramName: pn, minLength: minL, maxLength: maxL)

                            // append it to the aParams array
                            aParams.append(cd)

                        }

                    }

                    // create new JsonDataBiller object with
                    //      bname
                    //      bcategoryname
                    //      array of bcustomerparms
                    let jdBiller = JsonDataBiller(bname: localBName,
                                                  bcategoryname: localCName,
                                                  bcustomerparms: aParams)

                    // append the JsonDataBiller object to the appropriate category array
                    if localCName == "Water" {
                        self.jsonWaterData.append(jdBiller)
                    }
                    if localCName == "Electricity" {
                        self.jsonElectricityData.append(jdBiller)
                    }
                    // if localCName == ...

                }

                // finished parsing the data into arrays of jdBiller objects
                print("Water count: \(self.jsonWaterData.count)")
                print("Electricity count: \(self.jsonElectricityData.count)")
                print()

                // for quick debugging...
                self.jsonWaterData.forEach {
                    obj in
                    print("Name: \(obj.bname ?? "")")
                    print("Cat:  \(obj.bcategoryname ?? "")")
                    obj.bcustomerparms.forEach {
                        param in
                        print("Param: \(param.paramName ?? "") / minLength: \(param.minLength ?? "") / maxLength: \(param.minLength ?? "")")
                    }
                    print()
                }

//              DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                  self.tableView.reloadData()
//              }

            }catch {
                print("catch error")
            } }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo very  much... your solution is perfect, please do a small extension to your answer here... i got stuck here from long time,, please help me here.. i am jr developer i am unable to solve this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939991/why-one-bname-value-showing-its-paramname-count-times-in-tableview-while-parsing?noredirect=1#comment104151597_58939991

Comment: how to send all three param values to to next view controller, i am able to send only one param and that to not related to bname

Comment: here is sample code for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58939991/why-one-bname-value-showing-its-paramname-count-times-in-tableview-while-parsing?noredirect=1#comment104151597_58939991 is.....https://github.com/SwiftSamples/HomeIssue

Comment: @swift - ok, I made changes to your project based on the parsing approach in my answer. If you go to your GitHub repo and select `Options -> Collaborators` and add me (my GitHub id is "DonMag"), I can push my changes so you can see the differences.

Comment: sir you can push the code i have added you..  https://github.com/SwiftSamples/HomeIssue/invitations

Comment: @swift - I pushed my changes... take a look.

Comment: thank you soo very much for changes,    your changes are what exactly i want, thank you so much for your valuable time, i am really thank full to stackoverflow for such a great guidance and help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling with creating the struct, you may try to use this website which will do it automatically:

https://app.quicktype.io/

*Still, I would advice to first understand the concept and then use such helpers

In your case, there is an issue with your JSON file.

First part of your JSON should probably look like this:

{
  "id": 70,
  "bname": "Municipal Corporation - Water",
  "bcategoryname": "Water",
  "bcustomerparms": [
      { "paramName": "Consumer Number",
      "dataType": "numeric",
      "optional": false,
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 10}
]
}

```
// MARK: - DataStructure
struct DataStructure: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let bname, bcategoryname: String
    let bcustomerparms: [Bcustomerparm]
}

// MARK: - Bcustomerparm

struct Bcustomerparm: Codable {
    let paramName, dataType: String
    let bcustomerparmOptional: Bool
    let minLength, maxLength: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case paramName, dataType
    case bcustomerparmOptional = "optional"
    case minLength, maxLength
}
```

}